# If all sections of M have measure zero then M has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I'm stuck at the following exercise:
Let $(X,\mathcal A,\mu),(Y,\mathcal B,\nu)\;\;\sigma$-finite measure spaces and denote $\tilde\mu$ the completion of $\mu$ und $\mu\otimes\nu$ the product measure on $X\times Y$. 
For all $M\in\widetilde{\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B}$ and $x\in X$ let $M_x:=\{y\in Y \,|\, (x,y)\in M\}$.

Prove the following:
Let $M\in\widetilde{\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B}$ satisfy $M_x\in\tilde{\mathcal B}$ and $\tilde\nu(M_x)=0$ for $\mu$-almost every $x\in X$. Then one has:
$\widetilde{\mu\otimes\nu}(M)=0$.

This is how far I got:
Because of $M_x\in\tilde{\mathcal B}$ and $\tilde\nu(M_x)=0$ there is a $\nu$-null set $N(x)$ with $M_x\subset N(x)$. An obvious attempt would be to define a $\mu\otimes\nu$-null set by
$N:=\bigcup_{x\in X} N(x)$, but the problem is obvious: The union is not countable, so it's not clear whether $N\in \mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B$...

How can I circumvent this??

Comment: You can use the fact that $\mu\otimes\nu (M)=\int_X \nu (M_x)d\mu (X)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\overline{\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}}=\{C\cup N:C\in \mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B},N\in \mathcal{N} \}$ where $\mathcal{N}$ is the collection of subsets of $\mu\times\nu$-null-sets.

Hence for any $M \in \overline{\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}}$ there exists a $N\in \mathcal{N} $ and $C\in \mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}$ such that $M=C\cup N$. Thus $M\supset C$ and $M_x = \{y\in Y: (x,y)\in M \}\supset \{y\in Y: (x,y)\in C\}=C_x\in \mathcal{B}$. Hence $$\nu(C_x)=\overline{\nu}(C_x) \leq \overline{\nu}(M_x)=0,$$
for $\mu$-almost all $x\in X$. Thus 
$$
\overline{\mu\times\nu}(M) = \mu\times \nu (C) = \int_X \nu(C_x) \, d\mu(x) \leq 0,
$$
where we used the following theorem [image]

from [Bogachev's Measure theory - Volume 1](https://books.google.dk/books?id=CoSIe7h5mTsC&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=bogachev%20theorem%203.4.1&source=bl&ots=lSLuqsH7je&sig=EUssp9TvJB4XwVAWrK8pobuxcBQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjumsPlkI_PAhXI_ywKHZiBCocQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).